# Multiple select not inserting selected options to database in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, sqlite, express

How can I post values from a multiple select in a form? When I hit submit none of the selected values are posted.

This is my simple html form

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
        <select id="harvestDays" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
            <option>Monday</option>
            <option>Tuesday</option>
            <option>Wednesday</option>
            <option>Thursday</option>                
        </select>
        <input id="btnSubmit"value="submit">
</form>
```

on the script

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/days',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
            harvestDays: $('#harvestDays').val()
                }
            })

});

</script>
```

in my app.js(express server)

```
app.post('/days', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);
db.run(
    'INSERT into days VALUES  ($harvestDays)',
    {
$harvestDays: req.body.harvestDays
    } 
    );
});
```

When I select Tuesday and Wednesday, On the console the results are:

```
harvestDays: [ 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' ] }
```

However I expected a string separated by commas like:

```
harvestDays: 'Tuesday, Wednesday'
```

Note: on my database I have set type of my table field as a 'Text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a multiple select, `$('#harvestDays').val()` will give you the array of selected values. If you want it to be a comma-separated list, you can join them by appending `join()` like this:

```
$('#harvestDays').val().join();
```

By default, it'll separate the values with a comma (see [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)).

Comment: Note that Lukas' `toString()` suggestion works as well. I prefer `join()` in this situation because it's more explicit that it's "joining" separate elements, but the effect is the same in your situation.

Comment: thanks much! this is the smallest thing I was missing

Answer (score 0):

I think thats how you get the value from multiple select. But you can easy create the string you expectet by using

```
array.toString()
```